# Is it possible to change the text layout to something different(One Column,Two Column etc) in site pages?

Tags: page-layout

I would like to make a change to one of the existing "text layout" that is being used in site pages.
Click Url [here](https://ibb.co/YcdnfX6) see image

Instead of the highlighted one i want it to have 
 - on the first row i would like to have 2 columns instead of 1
So 
 - 2 columns (this is what i need changed here-split into 2)
 - 3 columns as it is right now
-  and a footer as is

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to create your own custom page layout in Pages library.

Comment: Thanks.So there is no other way to customise the pages in sitepages? The reason why i'm sticking to site pages is because i'm using sp.ui.responsive pnp and it only seems to work for pages created under sitepages

Comment: do you mean modern site pages or classic wiki pages  ?

Comment: how about instead of using a layout you create your own layout inserting multiple tables on a full page , or in a page and header layout ?

Comment: Thanks Mike I had that idea but wanted to just use webpart zones